# IE8 SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'locked' of undefined or null reference

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, stylesheet

I am struggling with this one problem. I don't understand why it's doing this, but in Internet Explorer I get this one error:

```
"IE8 SCRIPT5007: Unable to get property 'locked' of undefined or null reference "
```

I have no clue where it's getting 'locked' from. The following is where the code is located:

```
<HEAD>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/global.css" type="text/css"> 
<script>var isIE8 = false;</script>
<!--[if IE 8]>
<script>isIE8=true;</script> 
<![endif]-->
<TITLE>The App</TITLE>
</HEAD>
```

Of this, IE8 complains about the following line:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/global.css" type="text/css">
```

What's going on?

Comment: maybe you have [dynamic properties](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537634(v=vs.85).aspx) in that CSS file?

Comment: Um, is that all the code?

Comment: epascarello, no, this is the code snippet and its context.

Comment: Fabricio, I am not sure. It is a provided CSS file that has been minimized. Probably not but maybe.

Answer (score 0):

I'm working now in an IE8 fix, and I first installed an XP on a VM to have IE8 on it, without realizing IE11 has an emulation feature.

I'm using now IE11 emulation feature first, which Works pretty well, and pointed me to the right line instead of the line IE8 pointed me to, that was wrong... that might help you too.

After fixing my problems on IE11 emulation I turn into IE8 and test again... trust none...